# Need the exact pattern of preg_match to extract values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

I have a string separated with `;#<number>;#` as:

```
aaaa;#112;#bbbb;#113;#cccc;#112;#dddd
```

I want to find all `aaaa`, `bbbb` etc in array using `preg_match()`.

What should the regex pattern be?

What I was trying till now:

```
preg_match('/\;\#(?:[0-9]+)?/', $franchCont, $matches);
```

Comment: `match`? why not `split`? `preg_split('/;#\d+;#/', $string)`

Comment: @falsetru, yes, it works and thanks again :)

Comment: I am trying with: preg_match('/\;\#(?:[0-9]+)?/', $franchCont, $matches);, but preg_split as suggested by @falsetru worked for me

Comment: @aniruddha Don't edit the question to include the answer. Answers go below the page, you should move it there, or ask falsetru to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to split by delimiter; so [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is more appropriate function to use:

```
$parts = preg_split('/;#\d+;#/', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use split, or match.

Since you asked about match, one way would be

https://regex101.com/r/P5MPDf/1

`(?:;#\d+;#(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:(?!;#\d+;#).)+)`

Explained

```
 (?:
      ;\# \d+ ;\# (*SKIP) (*FAIL)   # Consume, but fail the delimiter
   |                              # or,
      (?:                           # Get all up until the delimiter
           (?! ;\# \d+ ;\# )
           . 
      )+
 )
```